# Define the language when using gettext __d() on CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, translation, gettext

I want to define with language I want to use on a single call to `__d()` (the gettext() CakePHP translation function).

I want something like:

`__d('domain', 'Hello World!', 'pt_BR');`

Even if my site is shown on **en_US**, I want that very message to be shown on a specific language.

Thanks!

Comment: I know that the thirt param is to return the message (on true). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this could work (untested though):

```
function __dl($domain, $str, $lang, $return = false) {
    $original = Configure::read('Config.language');
    Configure::write('Config.language', $lang);
    $str = __d($domain, $str, true);
    Configure::write('Config.language', $original);

    if ($return) {
        return $str;
    }
    echo $str;
}

__dl('domain', 'Foo bar', 'pt_BR');
```

Comment: great solution! i'll try and let you know