# Sending Multiple Emails in Different Language Consequently with CakePHP

Tags: email, cakephp, localization

I am sending emails to multiple recipients through a loop. The email elements use language localization. When I send these emails, I would like to send these emails in the user's native language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you change `Configure::write("Config.language")` to language which belongs to user to which the current e-mail is and after you use `__d()` or `__()` methods, you should have every email text in proper language

just translate via `__dl()` instead of basics.php `__d()` or `__()`

providing example from answer on SO question no.4294543

```
function __dl($domain, $str, $lang, $return = false) {
    $original = Configure::read('Config.language');
    Configure::write('Config.language', $lang);
    $str = __d($domain, $str, true);
    Configure::write('Config.language', $original);

    if ($return) {
        return $str;
    }
    echo $str;
}

__dl('domain', 'Foo bar', 'pt_BR');
```

<strike>or use parameter `language` in `__d()`</strike>

see:

- [Define the language when using gettext __d() on CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294543/define-the-language-when-using-gettext-d-on-cakephp)
- https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/cake/libs/i18n.php (line 134)